# How to make an LED turn on if the input voltage is below 5V?

Tags: voltage, switches, dc, voltage-measurement

First of all I'm  new to electronics. I am an automation engineer and a robotics integrator, so pretty specialized. Please be clear! Thanks all.

Context: PLC special circuit needs to stay at 5V otherwise the PLCs will face a potentially fatal problem (old tech.)

I need to make little circuit that I will use to visually minitor the voltage on some old PLCs. I have an input of 5V available to use for the circuit (5V coming from PLC.)
Simply just turns off the LED when ~5V are met, and turns ON the LED when under 5V (~4.7V) threshold.

Comment: Try looking for an undervoltage/brownout detector circuit or IC, it will probably satisfy your needs

Comment: ty im gonna look that up.

Comment: what does IC means btw ?

Comment: An IC is an integrated circuit, what most people know as a 'chip'.

Comment: do you think that TL7705ACP, PDIP 8 will work for my application ? i can read that it can gofrom 3v to 13,5v. how can i set the the 5v threshold ?

Comment: A TL7705ACP is **WAAAAAY** too complicated for your needs. And as a beginner, it will be e challenge to use that IC. Let me try and find a suitable schematic for you. I'm thinking of a TL431 based circuit.

Comment: thank you guys. there is like a trillion options out there and i need to find the most dirt-level skills friendly ^^. so im looking at what you give me with attention

Comment: As shown on page one of the [datasheet][1] in the reference circuits (you can essentially copy the 5v one), it depends on the model you buy. (The models range from TL7702A for 2.5 volts to TL7715A for 13.5 volts, see page 5). The TL7705 might work for you. PDIP is the easiest to use on breadboard or hand soldered, but as Bimpelrekkie mentioned it's a bit advanced. It might teach you a thing about using IC's though. 


  [1]: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl7702a.pdf

Answer (score 2):

To make a 5 V low voltage detector I'd try this circuit:

[image]

I found that [here](http://electronics-diy.com/lipoly-low-battery-indicator.php).

Changes you need to make:

There are 2 LEDs in series, I would use only **one** LED, so leave out LED2 (so connect the bottom side (cathode) of LED1 directly to -Battery (= ground).

To make the LED burn brighter, I make R1 = 1 kohm (instead of 2.2 kOhm).

R3 needs a different value, use 5.3 kOhm, that's not a standard value so use two resistors in series: 4.7 kOhm + 680 Ohms.

With that the LED should turn on when the (Battery) voltage drops below ~4.7 V.

With those changes, the end result is this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcCWHI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Yes, that TL431 is the symbol of a Thyristor, I know, I was too lazy to draw a proper symbol ;-) )

I didn't try this circuit but I'm quite sure it will do the job.

Comment: thanks for the help, realy needed it !

Comment: maybe my question is stupid, but how do you adjust the correct volt treshhold to the TL431 ?

Comment: *adjust the correct volt treshhold to the TL431* You **don't** ! The TL431 has  a **fixed**  threshold voltage of 2.5 V (actually 2.495 V, see datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1610597180525&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F ) if there's less than 2.5 V between ref and anode, there will be conduction between cathode and anode. If there's more than 2.5 V then there's no conduction.

Comment: If you want to be able to tune the threshold voltage **of the circuit** yourself, then make R4 not a 680 ohm resistor but a 2 kohm potmeter (variabe resistor). Then you can tune the circuit (by turning a knob) to make the LED switch at between 4 V and 5 V (roughly).

Comment: i would like to thank all of you for your help. i still have a question. in the last TL431 circuit, why wouldn't the current flow through the LED1 ? it's not in series. sorry for my english it's not my mother language .

Comment: The TL431 has a transistor between *cathode* and *anode*. This transistor is switched **ON** (causing the LED to go off) when the voltage between *ref* and *anode* is **larger** than 2.5 V. When te voltage at *ref* is smaller than 2.5 V, the transistor switches **OFF** so the current can flow through R1 and the LED making it light up.

Comment: I guess that you are more used to the normal situation where you would put a switch **in series** with a LED to make it switch on/off. However, you can also **short circuit** the LED so the current will go through the short instead of through the LED. Since there is also a resistor present (R1) making a short circuit is no issue, the resistor limits the current so nothing bad happens.

Comment: thanks, bulls eyes. you are correct i am used to actualy avoid short circuit anything because usualy i work on high tension (from 230V to 400V in tri)

Comment: Hi! i received the the parts yesterday and started wiring. i modified the circuit to not short the LED. i have an issue. the circuit actualy does the opposite of what i need. The LED turns on After the 2.495 V Threshhold and turns Off if less than 2.495V. i dont understand i wired it all like the scheme you gave me and still doesn't work. i can add pics of the circuit if you want.

Comment: i used this TL431 chip https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/references-de-tension/1695617/

Comment: *i am used to actualy avoid short circuit anything* Fair **BUT** in the circuits I propose it is OK to short the LED as there is a resistor that limits the current. Do you have a smartphone? It has chips that make millions and millions of short circuits (shorting the gate-source of a MOSFET) **every second**. In situations where **large currents can flow** making a short circuit is indeed **a bad idea**, but when the current is limited, there is no issue at all. So learn the difference!!!

Comment: *i modified the circuit to not short the LED* **WHY?** *the circuit actualy does the opposite of what i need.* That's because you modified it! Now build the circuit **exactly** as I have drawn it and try again.

Comment: I already did (the LED is always on). to be 100% sure i will do it again and report back

Comment: Yup, its Always ON i double checked everything

Comment: Try putting **two** LEDs in series, instead of only one, maybe your LED works on a very low voltage already. Using two in series can fix that.

Comment: Thank you ! Finaly working. How dumb i didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use opamp. set the opamp circuit something like -> if input1 of opamp < input2 give me and high output. This output can drive a simple 2n7002 mosfet to turn on or off the led.

So for this configuration you must have a second stable reference voltage, let say you have always 2.5 V in your circuit from a supply or reference generator etc. attain this voltage as opamp's input2. your input1 should be compared with input2 so you should set the input1 whenever it is 5V, at that time opamp input1 should be 2.5V, and if input1 is below 5V then the opamp input1 entry will be below 2.5V. So you need to connect 1/2 voltage divider to your input1 to compare with 2.5V ref. You may derive this logic for other reference voltage levels.

You can also use it for overvoltage.

Comment: A comparator would be a better choice than an op-amp. As the name suggests they are optimised for comparator functions and don't suffer the latch-up that can occur with op-amps, usually have higher current open-collector/drain outputs and will work with inputs down to ground.

Comment: Lots of text and that confuses everyone so include a schematic! Also, the circuit you're describing appears to be very similar to what is inside a TL431 chip, then only a couple of resistors are needed and we're done. On Ebay, a TL431 is less than 10 cents, you cannot beat that with an opamp and a MOSFET.

Comment: Opamp does not means just to be used for amplifiying. You may use as comparator which i use in avionics also. Im telling avionics because it requires so detailed verification and test processes. There can be always issues and  everything can be solved. For the second comment, yes i could attach schematic. My concerning was not beating, show different aspects which in electronics exists unlimited and which is also the purpose of this internet site.